# Parsing arguments while running script with IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, argparse

I often run scripts with `ipython -i` or `ipython --pdb`. I would like to make a script which parses arguments without interfering with being run in this manner. I've attempted to do this below in the file `ipy_parse.py`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-lf', '--proglogfile',
    help="File for logging",
    dest="plogfile",
    type=str
)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.plogfile)
```

However, when I run this with `ipython ipy_parse.py --proglogfile="wat"`, I get the following output:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Unrecognized alias: '--proglogfile=wat', it will probably have no effect.
None
```

Despite the fact that this script works normally when run with `python ipy_parse.py --proglogfile="wat"`. How can I parse arguments without interfering with `IPython` arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate ipython arguments from your script arguments using `--`:

```
ipython ipy_parse.py -- --proglogfile="wat"
```